# Auto highlighting input cells depending on input expression (eg its Head)

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

Is it possible to programmatically highlight (eg, by change background color) an input cell  conditional on the input expression's Head (or other attributes) upon evaluation?

For example, would like input cells with expressions whose `Head` is `Set` colored Blue, ones containing `Import` or `Export` colored `Green`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Perhaps, the simplest is to do something like this:

```
ClearAll[color];
SetAttributes[color, HoldAll];
color[_Export | _Import] := LightGreen;
color[_Set] := LightBlue;
color[_] := None;
```

and then

```
$Pre = 
  Function[
     code
     , 
     SetOptions[ EvaluationCell[], Background -> color[code]]; code
     , 
     HoldAll
  ];
```

Comment: Works as intended, but when I added another item, got a string of this msg: "The specified setting for the option Background cannot be used"

Comment: @alancalvitti Can you provide the exact code you added?

Comment: Actually I am getting these messages by clicking anywhere in a notebook not just in your code.

Comment: @alancalvitti This is weird. My code should not affect click events, only the cells being evaluated (via SHIFT+RETURN). Anyway, thanks for the accept.

Comment: after restarting M, no longer see warnings. However, existing input cells with Head = that I manually highlighted revert to no background color when evaluated, even if de-novo expressions turn blue as desired.

Comment: on inspection, adding semicolon changes the Head?

Comment: @alancalvitti Semicolon is interpreted as `CompoundExpression`, so it sure changes the head. In general, you may need a more elaborate expression parser, but it is still done along the lines of how `color` works. Re: revert to no highlighting - is this a problem? If yes, let me know and I'll post an update that won't revert already highlighted cells.

Comment: `CompoundExpression` works as you say and it's unexpectedly useful to highlight. However, I have persistent prolems with "The specified setting for the option Background cannot be used" - which is triggered even by mouse clicks and after quit/restart (without the code above.). Was a prefernce set?

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, that's because `color` is initially undefined. You could add the definition of `color` as an initialization cell, as a first cell in the notebook. Or, you could use something like `Background -> If[DownValues[color]=!={},color[code], None]`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre) as suggested by @LeonidShifrin is to use the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) option [`CellProlog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog) in a style sheet. Here is an example style sheet that does this:

```
ss = Notebook[
    {
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"],
        CellProlog :> Module[{cell = NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]], held, color},
            held = Replace[cell, Cell[b_, __] :> ToExpression[b, StandardForm, Hold]];
            held = Replace[held, Hold[b_;] :> Hold[b]];
            color = Replace[held,
                {
                Hold[_Set] -> LightBlue,
                Hold[_Import | _Export] -> LightGreen, 
                _ -> None
                }
            ];
            CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], Background] = color
        ]
    ]
    },
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
```

To use, evaluate:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> ss];
```

and then any Input cells you evaluate should turn color if they match your criteria.